# CodeDOM - Compilation Fails

Tags: c#, compilation, codedom

I am compiling a code using CodeDOM. First it was compiling all perfectly but now i am getting a problem at codeline 16:

```
 1        public void GenerateAssembly (bool inMemory, string assemblyName) {
 2               CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
 3               cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
 4               cp.GenerateInMemory = inMemory;
 5               cp.OutputAssembly = assemblyName;
 6               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
 7               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
 8               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
 9               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
10               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Entity.dll");
11               var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
12               providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
13               CodeDomProvider compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#", providerOptions);
14               compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilationParameters, sourceCode)
15               buildErrors = compilationResult.Errors;
16               lastBuild = compilationResult.CompiledAssembly;
17       }
```

The error i m getting is:

```
FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///[project_location]\bin\Debug\Dynamic.dll'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

---

EDIT 1
What is the source code?

sorry i forgot to attach all the class, here you can see it completely:

```
 1 public class CustomCompile {
 2        private string[] sourceCode;
 3        public string[] SourceCode { get { return sourceCode; } }
 4        public CompilerErrorCompilation buildErrors;
 5        public Assembly lastBuild;
 6        public CustomCompile (string[] sourceCode) {
 7               this.sourceCode = sourceCode;
 8        }
 9        public void GenerateAssembly (bool inMemory, string assemblyName) {
10               CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
11               cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
12               cp.GenerateInMemory = inMemory;
13               cp.OutputAssembly = assemblyName;
14               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
15               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
16               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
17               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
18               cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Entity.dll");
19               var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
20               providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
21               CodeDomProvider compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#", providerOptions);
22               compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilationParameters, sourceCode)
23               buildErrors = compilationResult.Errors;
24               lastBuild = compilationResult.CompiledAssembly;
25       }
26 }
```

---

EDIT 2
Example

```
   var scriptA = "using System;\nusing System.Collection;\nclass Test {\n\tvoid Init () { Console.WriteLine (\"Void Init got called\"); }\n}";
   var compile = new CustomCompile(new string[] {});
   compile.GenerateAssembly (false, "Dynamic.dll");
   // -- or --
   compile.GenerateAssembly (true, "Dynamic.dll");
```

2nd ex

```
   var compile = new CustomCompile(new string[] {System.IO.File.ReadAllText ("C:\\Users\\[Username]\\Desktop\\CommandExecuter - Copy.cs")});
   compile.GenerateAssembly (false, "Dynamic.dll");
   // -- or --
   compile.GenerateAssembly (true, "Dynamic.dll");
```

http://pastebin.com/PGWbKFdD

Comment: What is in `sourceCode`?

Comment: string[] sourceCode, contains all the codes i need to compile inside the assembly

Comment: I understand that, but what does it *actually* contain, like give us an example.

Comment: @RonBeyer added 2 examples, both are actually used during the work

Comment: Does build errors contain anything in it when you get this error?

Comment: Don't try to access *CompiledAssembly* when there are any build errors, it won't exist.

Comment: ya i have 2 errors, i think that is the reason, i forgot to mention that there is a script which references an assembly before compiling. it was adding "using ;" but no name of namespace. going to see if this fixes the bug

Comment: @RonBeyer  awesome guys, perfect, found the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant ya it was deleting the dll, now i will check for errors first, then if all fine get the dll

Answer (score 0):

If the source codes we are compiling have any error, then CodeDOM deletes the dll after compilation, or may it never creates it. In each case the value of CompiledAssembly is null, so be sure the code you are compiling. Before going to take the compiled assembly check for errors, in the case we any one, break before taking the created dll.